# How to pass 'this' into a setTimeout callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, settimeout

*css*

```
.item {
  display: none;
}
```

*html*

```
<div>
  <div class="item">machin</div>
  <div class="item">chose</div>
  <div class="item">chouette</div>
  <div class="item">prout</div>
</div>
```

I'm using jQuery and I'd like to make each `.item` appearing after a random little timer like:

*javascript*

```
$('.item').each(function () {
  itm = $(this);
  setTimeout(function () {
    itm.fadeIn(1000);
  }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
})
```

Here `itm` will always contain the last item because the function is evaluated after all assignments.
I can't use the 3rd parameter of `setTimeout()` because it will not work on IE.
It's not advised to use `setTimeout()` with the *eval* method for security reasons.

So how can I access to my object through `setTimeout()` ?

---

**Edit**

I know that this question have already been posted.
But I though that it were slightly specific with the `each()` context.
Now someone have entirely changed the title of my question that was originally something like *'setTimeout() - jQuery.each() this object parameter'*

Comment: `this` inside of `setTimeout()` refers to the global object. Your code above shouldn't even work for the last item.

Comment: Sorry I was actually doing `itm = $(this)` in my code instead of `var itm = $(this)`, I updated my question. Then now I don't know which answer to accept :)

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY Aha.  The difference between `var itm` and `itm` is that without `var` it is a single global variable, instead of a local variable for each call of the enclosing function.  That's why the setTimeout only ever saw the last element in the list.

Comment: That was actually the problem

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do not use setTimeout, use jQuery own tools.

```
$('.item').each(function () {
   $(this).delay(Math.random() * 1000).fadeIn();
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/qENhd/

Comment: @ShankarSangoli: sure it does.

Comment: If you notice the `div's` don't `fadeIn` in sequence as it should be.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli I don't see any reason that it wouldn't work. Remember, this isn't a for-loop, therefore it doesn't have the same issues.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli: this is not a requirement, at least, the original code doesn't do that.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working with Bootstrap 3 tooltips? `$('#elem').tooltip('show').delay(5000).tooltip('hide');` the hide seems to fire immediately.

Answer (score 13):

Create/Utilize a `closure`:

```
$('.item').each(function () {
  var that = this;

  setTimeout(function () {
    $(that).fadeIn(1000);
  }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
})
```

http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: Since the OP can't get JQuery's built-in tools to work, this is by far the simplest and most straightforward

Answer (score 3):

Before `setTimeout` executes `each` loop would have finished executing, it will not wait. Also inside `setTimeout` function `this` will not refer to the DOM element.

Try something like this.

```
function fadeItem(item){
   item.fadeIn(1000);
}

$('.item').each(function () {
  var $item = $(this);
  setTimeout(function () {
    fadeItem($item);
  }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
});
```

You can also try something like this.

```
var $items = $('.item'), count = 0;

function fadeItem(item){
   item.fadeIn(1000);
    if(count < $items.length){
       setTimeout(function(){
            fadeItem($items.eq(count++));
       }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
    }
}
setTimeout(function(){
    fadeItem($items.eq(count++));
}, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to store `this` in a separate variable:

```
$('.item').each(function () {
  var me = $(this);
  setTimeout(function () {
    me.fadeIn(1000);
  }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is to save `this` into a local that can be evaluated safely in the `setTimeout` callback

```
$('.item').each(function () {
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function () {
    $(self).fadeIn(1000);
  }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.item').each(function () {
 var myVar = $(this);
setTimeout(function () {
myVar.fadeIn(1000);
}, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this insteed:

```
    $('.item').each(function () {
        var elm = this;
      setTimeout(function () {
        $(elm).fadeIn(1000);
      }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
    })
```

I can't explain why it works, but i think this is a reference to another "this" in your setTimeout.

http://jsfiddle.net/Pdrfz/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 $('.item').each(function () {
    var item =$(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
            item.fadeIn(1000);
        },
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
   });
```